# How to create a roll back of a table that you updated in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql query that updates a table based on a condition.I am creating a migration file in visual studio, how do i go about adding a roll back to ensure that the changes i updated into a file goes back to how it was.

```
INSERT INTO Table(ID,Name,SiteID,Surname)
SELECT 
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ID),
     Name,
     10100,
     Surname,

FROM Table
WHERE SiteID = 10000 --so it will copy this data 10000 and make a new entry of 10100
```

Can you advise on how to create a rollback so that it will delete all the 10100 entries and go back to been how it was

can I just say ?

```
delete 
from table
where siteID=10100
```

Is this efficient? for a roll back

Comment: Yes that looks sufficient rollback query.

Comment: BEGIN TRAN SQL code ROLLBACK TRAN

Comment: If your table had other rows with siteID=10100  prior to your insert, your DELETE will successfully delete these rows too

Answer (score 0):

A `DELETE` statement, is just that, a `DELETE` statement. Rolling back something means undoing what has so far been done in the **uncommitted** transaction. This may not be "deleting", it might be undoing an `UPDATE`, or returning a row that was previously deleted, or even DDL changes.

In your case, if you want to remove the row you inserted earlier, then a `DELETE` statement is what you're after. That's not rolling back though. Here's an example of a `ROLLBACK` (and `COMMIT`):

```
--BEGIN a Transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION Creation;
--Create a table
CREATE TABLE #Sample (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), String varchar(10));
-- insert a row
INSERT INTO #Sample (String)
VALUES ('Hello');
--Rollback the transactions
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Creation;
--Now, not only has the row never been inserted, the table was not created!
--This will error
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO
--Now, let's create and COMMIT that table this time:
BEGIN TRANSACTION Creation2;
--Create a table
CREATE TABLE #Sample (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), String varchar(10));
-- insert a row
INSERT INTO #Sample (String)
VALUES ('Hello');
--And commit
COMMIT TRANSACTION Creation2;
GO
--Hazaar! data
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO
--And finally, a little play around with some data

BEGIN TRANSACTION Data1;

INSERT INTO #Sample (String)
VALUES ('These'),('are'),('more'),('values');

--Let's Delete the Hello as well
DELETE
FROM #Sample
WHERE ID = 1;

--Inspect mid transction
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

--Rollback!
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Data1;
--Oh, the values have gone!
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

--Notice, however, the ID still increments:
INSERT INTO #Sample (String)
VALUES ('Goodbye');

--Goodbye is ID 6
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

GO
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Hope that helps explain what a `ROLLBACK` is for you in SQL Server terms.